# Random shuffling of tags in react

Tags: html, reactjs, random, tags, shuffle

I am building a quiz program in react and pulling my questions from a mysql db into an array and then displaying the different parts in html rows. Right now I'm always pulling the correct answer into button 1 and three incorrect answers into buttons 2-4.  Is there a way for me to shuffle the rows randomly so that I don't have to create a separate array and then shuffle?

```
<div className='answers'>
    <Row><button onClick={correctAnswer}>}</button></Row>
    <Row><button onClick={incorrectAnswer1}></button></Row>
    <Row><button onClick={incorrectAnswer2}></button></Row>
    <Row><button onClick={incorrectAnswer3}></button></Row>
</div>
```

Comment: There are just about any number of ways to "shuffle" your data, what have you tried? I suggest using the [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm as it does a stable shuffle in a single pass.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're completely opposed to shuffling the original array, you could always build a secondary array that reveals which row maps to your original array. Something like

```
let answerKey = [3, 1, 2, 0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```
const shuffle = (array) => {
  let currentIndex = array.length;
  let randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (currentIndex != 0) {
    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex--;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
      array[randomIndex],
      array[currentIndex],
    ];
  }

  return array;
};

const Answers = ({ children }) => {
  const Options = React.Children.toArray(children);
  return <div className="answers">{shuffle(Options)}</div>;
};

Answers.propTypes = {
  answers: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.node).isRequired,
};

<Answers>
  <Row><button onClick={correctAnswer}>}</button></Row>
  <Row><button onClick={incorrectAnswer1}></button></Row>
  <Row><button onClick={incorrectAnswer2}></button></Row>
  <Row><button onClick={incorrectAnswer3}></button></Row>
</Answers>
```